# When creating an expression in QGIS, is there a way to reference the next record and previous record?

Tags: qgis, cartography

I have a set of points from a GPX file, and would like to create a heatmap from them, with the points weighted on the amount of time spent at that point.

I want to create a calculated field in QGIS, where duration will equal, either T-t where 'T' is the timestamp at the next point and 't' is the timestamp of the current point; or even better, (T-t)/2 + (t-s)/2 where 's' is the timestamp of the previous point.

However I'm unclear on how to bring values from other records into an expression.

Comment: To reference another row in a table usually means to establish a join to another instance of the same table. I think this is beyond the scope of field calculator. Is calculation with Python script an option? You could iterate through the sorted table, save the timestamps in variables and assign the calculated value to a new field

Comment: I think the first thing is to convert the gpx file to shape file in order that you can modify the attribute table and define a new column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends... If your layer has a sequential id-type field then you can use the get_feature function. This function takes a layer name, field name and value and returns the first matching record from that layer. You'd then use the "attribute" function to retrieve your desired attribute value from the feature.  Eg, if your layer is called "my_layer", sequential id field is " sequence_number" and the attribute you want to retrieve is called "time", then the expression is:

```
 attribute( get_feature( 'my_layer', 'sequence_number', "sequence_number" + 1), "time")
```

Pay careful attention to where " and ' are used.

Comment: Just trying this out now. Having seen what you've put, what wasn't initially obvious now seems clear, that you only use " when you want to recall the value of a field.

When I try an expression like you've written I don't get an error message, so I know it is a valid expression. However I've found QGIS then crashes when I try and view the attribute table.

Comment: Where are you using this expression? Is it a virtual field?

Comment: Yeah (and then enough characters to reach the minimum)

Comment: It shouldn't crash (that's bad) but I suspect the reason is that using this function in a virtual field causes an infinite loop. Eg, to calculate the values for a feature it has to get the next feature, which then requires the next, etc... Try using the field calculator and updating a real field instead of creating a virtual one.

Comment: Just tried this at 3.20.2 with a real table/field, not virtual.  No error was thrown, but the calculated field values were all NULL.  I tried it will output fields as integer, decimal, text, and time.  No joy...